# Integration of Stripe with iOS and PHP

Tags: ios

I am new to iOS programming.

I am trying to integrate Stripe to my `iOS app`.

It gives me the following error.

> First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation
>   0x037c1946 **exceptionPreprocess + 182    1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x03075a97 objc_exception_throw + 44  2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x037c186d +[NSException raise:format:] + 141     3   ValenX
>
>   0x00343c63 +[Stripe validateKey:] + 163   4   ValenX
>
>   0x0034539a +[Stripe
>   createTokenWithCard:publishableKey:operationQueue:completion:] + 314
>     5   ValenX                              0x0034612e +[Stripe
>   createTokenWithCard:publishableKey:completion:] + 222     6   ValenX
>
>   0x00345fff +[Stripe createTokenWithCard:completion:] + 175    7   ValenX
>   0x000cf59f -[V_BuyStripeVC saveButtonAction:] + 879   8
>
>   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0308b7cd -[NSObject
>   performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 84  9   UIKit
>
>   0x01aea23d -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 99     10 
>   UIKit                               0x01aea1cf -[UIApplication
>   sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 64    11  UIKit
>
>   0x01c1de86 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 69  12  UIKit
>
>   0x01c1e2a3 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 598    13 
>   UIKit                               0x01c1d50d -[UIControl
>   touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 660    14  UIKit
>
>   0x01b3a60a -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 874    15  UIKit
>
>   0x01b3b0e5 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 791   16  UIKit
>
>   0x01b00549 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242  17  UIKit
>
>   0x01b1037e _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 20690    18  UIKit 
>   0x01ae4b19 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 2206  19  CoreFoundation
>
>   0x036e51df __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION**
>   + 15  20  CoreFoundation                      0x036daced __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 253  21  CoreFoundation                      0x036da248 __CFRunLoopRun + 952     22  CoreFoundation
>   0x036d9bcb CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 443     23  CoreFoundation
>   0x036d99fb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123   24  GraphicsServices
>   0x0510624f GSEventRunModal + 192  25  GraphicsServices
>   0x0510608c GSEventRun + 104   26  UIKit
>   0x01ae88b6 UIApplicationMain + 1526   27  ValenX
>   0x000cf0ce top_level_code + 78    28  ValenX
>   0x000cf10b main + 43  29  libdyld.dylib
>   0x04105ac9 start + 1 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught
>   exception of type NSException

**Below is the code.**

```
#import <AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h>
#import "Stripe.h"
#import "V_BuyStripeVC.h"
#import "PTKView.h"
#import "STPToken.h"

#define STRIPE_TEST_PUBLIC_KEY @"pk_test_vh4FFxERgMGtcs344RkWEfpC"
#define STRIPE_TEST_POST_URL @"http://s547905537.onlinehome.us/ValenX/serverauth.json"

@interface V_BuyStripeVC ()<PTKViewDelegate>
@property(weak, nonatomic) PTKView *paymentView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *saveButton;
@end

@implementation V_BuyStripeVC

- (IBAction)saveButtonAction:(UIButton *)sender {

    STPCard *card = [[STPCard alloc] init];
    //STPToken *token = [[STPToken alloc]init];
    card.number = self.paymentView.card.number;
    card.expMonth = self.paymentView.card.expMonth;
    card.expYear = self.paymentView.card.expYear;
    card.cvc = self.paymentView.card.cvc;

    [Stripe createTokenWithCard:card completion:^(STPToken *token, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            [self handleError:error];
        } else {
            [self postStripeToken:token];
        }
    }];

}


- (void)postStripeToken:(STPToken* )token {

    //1
    /*
    NSURL *postURL = [NSURL URLWithString:STRIPE_TEST_POST_URL];
    AFHTTPClient* httpClient = [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:postURL];
    httpClient.parameterEncoding = AFJSONParameterEncoding;
    [httpClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
    [httpClient setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"text/json"];
     */

    //2
    // RWCheckoutCart* checkoutCart = [RWCheckoutCart sharedInstance];
    NSInteger totalCents = 20000;

    //3
    NSMutableDictionary* postRequestDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    postRequestDictionary[@"stripeAmount"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", totalCents];
    postRequestDictionary[@"stripeCurrency"] = @"usd";
    postRequestDictionary[@"stripeToken"] = token;
    postRequestDictionary[@"stripeDescription"] = @"Purchase from FoodApp iOS app!";

    //4
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [manager POST:@"http://s547905537.onlinehome.us/ValenX/serverauth.php" parameters:postRequestDictionary  success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        [self chargeDidSucceed];
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        [self chargeDidNotSuceed];
    }];

    self.saveButton.enabled = YES;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    PTKView *view = [[PTKView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15,20,290,55)];
    self.paymentView = view;
    self.paymentView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:self.paymentView];
}

- (void)paymentView:(PTKView *)view withCard:(PTKCard *)card isValid:(BOOL)valid
{
    // Toggle navigation, for example
    self.saveButton.enabled = valid;
}

- (void)handleError:(NSError *) error {

    //1
    if ([error.domain isEqualToString:@"StripeDomain"]) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                        message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }

    //2
    else {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                        message:@"Please try again"
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }

    self.saveButton.enabled = YES;
}

- (void)chargeDidSucceed {

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success"
                                                    message:@"Please enjoy your meal."
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];

    //Send confirmation email
    //RWEmailManager* emailManager = [[RWEmailManager alloc] initWithRecipient:self.nameTextField.text
                                                              //recipientEmail:self.emailTextField.text];

    //[emailManager sendConfirmationEmail];

    //RWCheckoutCart* checkoutCart = [RWCheckoutCart sharedInstance];
    //[checkoutCart clearCart];

    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (void)chargeDidNotSuceed {
    //2
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Payment not successful"
                                                    message:@"Please try again later."
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}

@end
```

I am stuck with this for last 1 week. Any help is appreciated.

Regards,
Anand

Comment: can you please add your project to github and post the link.

Comment: I suggest you reformat your hideously formatted error message. Putting it in a code block should make it readable.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try give the publishable key under Stripe.m, you can get publishable key from Stripe -> Account Settings -> API

static NSString *defaultKey =

Since I have used a test card starting with 4242, I get an alert message with "Payment Not Successful"

Hope this helps.